# Angular Library is not able include third party library in the bundle

Tags: angular, webpack-4, angular-library, ng-build, angular-cli-v7

My requirement is to create libraries which have their own view and according to a User's configuration, the library will be fetched from AWS S3 Bucket and included in the final app on runtime.
[See this example](https://github.com/lmeijdam/angular-umd-dynamic-example). I am able to add the `dist/library/bundles/library.lib.umd.js` in the main app and show it to user. But when I try to use third party libraries like `uuid`, `moment` or `ng2-dragula`, the `ng build` command does not include any third party library in the final bundle. I get warning like

```
'ng2-dragula' is imported by ..\..\dist\torab-custom-lib\esm5\lib\custom-lib.service.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
```

while building the library and my app in which the `projects/library` exists shows

```
ERROR in dist/torab-custom-lib/lib/custom-lib.component.d.ts(2,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ng2-dragula
```

What I want is to include any third party library I use in the final bundle as I am not able to install/import them on runtime. I have tried

```
"bundledDependencies": [
    "ng2-dragula"
  ]
```

in `package.json` as suggested [here](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/1231#issuecomment-471195677) and

```
"embedded": [
    "ng2-dragula"
      ],
```

in my `ng-package.json` suggested [here](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/744#issuecomment-378840061). This is my environment info

```
Angular CLI: 7.1.4
Node: 11.10.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.1.4
... animations, cli, common, compiler, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.11.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.13.5
@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr   0.11.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.13.5
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.13.5
@angular-devkit/core               7.1.4
@angular-devkit/schematics         7.1.4
@angular/compiler-cli              7.2.9
@ngtools/json-schema               1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack                   7.3.5
@schematics/angular                7.1.4
@schematics/update                 0.11.4
ng-packagr                         4.7.1
rxjs                               6.3.3
typescript                         3.1.6
webpack                            4.29.0
```

Please help. Also please suggested if there is a different way to load third party library on runtime in the app.

Comment: I think you need to use the `npm pack` and `npm publish` from `bundledDependencies`. That's what the ng-packgr docs suggest

Answer (score 0):

After building you library, use rollupjs to bundle third party libraries from fesm5 file.

Here is my rollup.config :

```
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import sourcemaps from 'rollup-plugin-sourcemaps';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';

export default {
    plugins: [
       resolve(), 
       sourcemaps(),
       commonjs({
        namedExports: { 
            'node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js': ['Chart' ]
        }
      })
   ],
   onwarn: () => { return },
   output: {
       format: 'umd',
       name: 'mylib',
       globals: globals,
       sourcemap: true,
       amd: { id: 'mylib' }
    }
}
```

Then I use this rollup command :

```
 rollup -c rollup.config.js -i .\dist\mylib\fesm5\mylib.js -o .\dist\mylibwiththirdparty.umd.js
```